# Remove dot from file extension

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17, std

I have path variable

```cpp
using fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path p = "file.txt";
```

I can get file extension by using

```cpp
p.extension() // returns ".txt"
```

I need to remove a dot from file extension. I can do it by using substrings and constructing path again:

```cpp
fs::path(p.extension().string().substr(1)) // returns "txt"
```

Is there any other way to get file extension without a dot?

Comment: If you absolutely want to have a path object then your code is the way to go. Otherwise I would recommend using `string`, and then `.find` plus `.substr`.

Comment: Why must the file extension be stored as `std::filesystem::path`? Couldn't be stored as `std::string` as well? Btw. I'm not aware of any improvement or alternative. (But I must admit I'm not using `std::filesystem` so long as well.)

Comment: I just stumbled into [std::filesystem::path::replace_extension()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/replace_extension) which has an argument of type `path`. This might explain why it could make sense to store an extension as `std::filesystem::path`. However, according to the examples, `replace_extension()` works well with extensions regardless whether there is a leading dot or not.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension 
Clear guidelines about the function behavior.